# OpenAI GPT-3 API: Why do I get different, non-related random responses to the same question every time?

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api, gpt-3

I am using the “text-davinci-003” model and I copied the code form the OpenAI playground, but the bot keeps giving me random response to a simple “Hello” everytime.

This is the code I am using :

```
response: dict = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-003",
                                                    prompt=prompt,
                                                    temperature=0.9,
                                                    max_tokens=150,
                                                    top_p=1,
                                                    frequency_penalty=0,
                                                    presence_penalty=0.6,
                                                    stop=[" Human:", " AI:"])
        choices: dict = response.get('choices')[0]
        text = choices.get('text')
        print(text)
```

The response to simple “hello” chat 3 different times :

1. the first time it gave me a hello world program for Java
2. second time it answered correctly - ‘Hi there! How can I help you today?’
3. third time:

   ```
     def my_method
           puts "hello"
        end
      end
    end

   # To invoke this method we would call:
   MyModule::MyClass.my_method
   ```

I just dont get it, as using the same simple ‘hello’ prompt in the OpenAI's playground gives me accurate response eveytime - 'Hi there! How can I help you today?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/completion/prompt-design):

> The temperature and top_p settings control how deterministic the model
> is in generating a response. **If you're asking it for a response where
> there's only one right answer, then you'd want to set these lower.** If
> you're looking for more diverse responses, then you might want to set
> them higher. The number one mistake people use with these settings is
> assuming that they're "cleverness" or "creativity" controls.

Change this...

```
temperature = 0.9
```

...to this.

```
temperature = 0
```